# How do you check if the device has a camera with reflection?

Tags: android

I'm adapting an app so it will work on the KindleFire, which doesn't have a camera.

I don't have any Android devices that lack a camera, so I don't know if the following code actually will `return false` for the Kindle.  I'm using reflection because my app has already been released with Donut compatibility, and Donut doesn't have `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()`.

I'm assuming Donut devices all have cameras--hasn't caused me trouble yet.

```
public static boolean isCameraAvailable(Context context){
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    return tryHasSystemFeature(pm,"android.hardware.camera");
}

private static Method packageManager_hasSystemFeature;

static {
    initCompatibility();
};

private static void initCompatibility() {
    try {
        packageManager_hasSystemFeature = PackageManager.class.getMethod(
                "hasSystemFeature", new Class[] { String.class } );
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        //leave the Method null
    }
}

static private boolean tryHasSystemFeature(PackageManager pm,String feature){
    if (packageManager_hasSystemFeature != null) {
        try {
            final Boolean hasIt = (Boolean) packageManager_hasSystemFeature.invoke(pm,feature);
            return hasIt.booleanValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's recommended to add this line in your manifest file, if you want to be sure the device has a camera:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Market will prevent a device without a camera from downloading your application.

Comment: My app does use the camera. It's just not critical, so I need to hide certain features if there is no camera. Otherwise, I'd be wasting my time trying to update it for the Kindle. Thanks.

Comment: @TenFour04, You may also think about creating two versions of your application: with camera support and without it. The Android Market supports multiple apk and will automatically offer user a right version for his device.

Comment: Thanks, I know that's an option. But if I could just test my above code somehow, I wouldn't have to end up managing multiple apks.